# (How) does nonlinear regression work in LibreOffice Calc with two arbitrary curves?

Tags: non-linear-regression

I'm trying to model the pandemic by calculating a daily case fatality ratio and using it to extrapolate future deaths in the short term with an estimated lag time between cases and deaths that ramps from zero to maximum to model improvements in testing. I'm calculating

```
current deaths/prior cases*current cases
```

to extrapolate future deaths. I'm doing something similar with total tests conducted in place of cases because averaging these two functions seems to help.

I couldn't manually find a local maximum with the built-in correlation function, but fit-by-eye measures above 0.98. The smaller the lag time, the higher the correlation, even though it's visually obvious that this is the wrong answer. However, zero lag time does converge on the current deaths data, so...?

I tried sum of squares and couldn't find a local minimum that way either. So what I resorted to was

```
multiplying the difference in slopes by the difference in magnitude
```

for each extrapolated deaths data point versus the corresponding data point in the deaths time series, and

```
minimizing the square of the errors visually on a plot.
```

I tried other functions such as exponential and arccotangent, but didn't find anything that seemed to help. I'm out of my depth and floundering.

Is what I'm doing with the product of slope error and magnitude error a known thing? I figured that was as close to nonlinear regression as I was going to get without help.

I'm sorry for being obtuse. I'm doing this all on my own.

Edit: I can't seem to add pictures. I'll try adding a link to external pictures.

[my illustrations](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1052688105306449&id=100016958088293&__cft__%5B0%5D=AZVJRKa1Nbj6EN7AKI78UYfHgrLYd4R1yJAUEUJAHUzpo6kdx63NoRcPGSUUThnuylSdSWs4-pVet8yKo-NGuS3bk7n7TpkWQbEcd43GEIqWsUFfUeHvz-OeaSKOcYmWLVg&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R)